# How to override base web-to-lead component styling in LWR with a static resource stylesheet

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, web2lead, lwr

I am using the lead form in the experience builder (With no theme), and I am trying to style it. However, I seem to be hitting a brick wall.

Here is my code:

Head Markup:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sfsites/c/resource/SUP_resources/Styles/setGlobalStyleingOverride" />
```

CSS File:

```
.dxp-button-large > .slds-button {
  --sds-c-button-shadow: rgb(32, 204, 83);
  --sds-c-button-shadow-focus: blue;
  --sds-c-button-inverse-shadow-focus: rgb(148, 72, 114);
  --sds-c-button-neutral-color-background: rgb(255, 123, 0);
  --sds-c-button-neutral-color-border-hover: rgb(216, 119, 27);
}
```

Nothing is taking effect.

Here is the HTML output:
[image: rendered html]

Can someone please try and guide me with this? The above code is just for the button, but would need to restyle the entire form itself.

Unless there is a way to do this in a custom component that may be easier? Issue is, when I use the web-to-lead markup and add classes to that, nothing happens, which I suspect is due to the synthetic DOM, but my understanding of how that works is extremely baseline.